# Is it okay to seed the randomizer more than once if done this way?

Tags: c, loops, random, random-seed

Say I have this loop:

```
for (i=0; i < 100; i++)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    printf("%d\n", rand());
}
```

If my machine is reasonably fast, it should print the same number 100 times.

But if I modify it like this:

```
for (i=0; i < 100; i++)
{
    srand(time(NULL) + rand());
    printf("%d\n", rand());
}
```

Then it should print 100 different numbers. My question is, is there anything wrong in seeding the randomizer like this? What about efficiency? Does it significantly reduce the efficiency?

A side question, if I seed the randomizer in the `main()` function once, is it enough for other functions as well (i.e. I do not need to seed it again in another function which uses `rand()`)?

**EDIT**

There is a reason why I may need to use this way (unless of course there is a better way which I don't know). Say I have a custom library with a function that uses `rand()`. But that function does not know whether randomizer was seeded before or not. In that case, I put `srand(time(NULL) + rand())` in that function to make sure that the randomizer is seeded even if it was not seeded before.

Example:

```
int main()
{
    int i;

    srand(time(NULL));  // Seeded here, but the print_rand() function does not know it

    for (i=0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        print_rand();
    }

    return(0);
}


// Pretend this function is in a library
void print_rand()
{
    srand(time(NULL) + rand()); // No guarantee if seeding was done before, so doing it here

    printf("%d\n", rand());
}
```

**EDIT 2**

I just tested it with 1000000 loops. Seeding once took `0.024s` and seeding every time took `4.972s`. So I guess it does add up to significant performance decrease if it is a large loop.

Comment: Seeding the randomizer once should suffice for most applications. Otherwise you should look into other (more specialized) randomizers anyway.

Comment: If you want something which is truly random, then you shouldn't use `rand()`/`srand()`. Use Intel Secure Key instead (available on Intel CPUs since 2006).

Comment: The question is _why_ you would want to seed it more than once. It is like asking: "I need a red house. Is it ok to paint my house red 100 times instead of just once?"

Comment: Thanks, much clearer now. I don't mean to use it for something _very_ secure. It's only for small games and such. Please see edit.

Comment: You could use a static variable to remember if you seeded already.
static int seeded = 0; if(!seeded) { srand(...); seeded=1; }

Answer (score 2):

It is generally wrong to seed a PRNG more than once. It really doesn't increase the security of the PRNG nor makes it faster (maybe slower!)

**A PRNG just need to be seeded once**

And yes, it's enough to seed it in one place. Another story would be if you had multiple instances of the same prng but that's not the case, that's C not C++ and rand() is static.

It's all about what you want to do with the random data...

- Crypto stuff? forget using rand(), srand() and time()
- randomize some
  game AI? it could be ok

Answer (score 2):

Don't do it.

Seed it once.

`srand(time(NULL) + rand());` will introduce statistical bias if used repeatedly. Intuitively this is due to two effects: (i) `srand(rand())` will effectively omit every other number which will increase the variance and (ii) the `srand(time(NULL))` will introduce an additional additive constant which will cause the modulo operator in the generator to be invoked more often than it ought. You might even compromise the periodicity of the generator.

Why not test it? I expect that the mean will be broadly correct, but I imagine the variance, and higher moments, will be off.

Comment: you're right about the bias, but that's just because the rand() is a linear cong. generator.

Comment: Reseeding produces bias, but there is no bias from adding an offset to the seed so long as you only do it once.  Seeding a PRNG is choosing an entry point to its cycle, adding a shift just moves the entry point.  The cycle of numbers produced is identical regardless of where you climb on board, as long as you don't reseed.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to want to improve the output from `rand`.

1. Your method will not do this. Since your code will most likely be known, anyone can see what you did and then your method is equivalent to calling `srand` just once.
2. Even without knowing your code, just knowing that you use `rand`, the numbers generated from it will on most systems be easily predictable.

`rand` is only useful for very simple situations where something is meant to look randomish to a human. Like a simple game. And in those situations calling `srand` once is plenty enough.

If you're actually looking to generate random (defined as "unpredictable") numbers, you shouldn't use `rand` or `random`. Then you need to do some research for your operating system and look into a proper library that generates random numbers.

To answer the question. It shouldn't hurt doing that. Maybe you'll make the predictable numbers even more predictable. Maybe the biased numbers will be slightly more biased. A human (the only entity that can be fooled by `rand`) will still probably see them as random enough. On the other hand, you gain nothing from doing this, so why waste time?